# Writing content from struct into a file using fwrite

Tags: c, networking, network-programming

I am trying to write data from struct into a a file. For instance the data is found in newpackets.data. I am trying to write that into a file, but keep getting segfault. I have looked at other questions on here, but could not find a solution. Adding my code below. How can i solve this issue ? Thank you

to run server do `./server 8500 1`

to run client do `./client 127.0.0.1 8500 500 3 ex.txt exout.txt`

`ex.txt` will need to be made and then write random words into it. for instance can be like 85 characters

```
  //server side 

    #include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <strings.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>

#include  <stdint.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <errno.h>

#include "sys/un.h"

#define MAXLINE 32768
struct ackdata
{
  int ack;
};

struct packetdata
{
  int seqnumber;
  int lenght;
  char data[MAXLINE];
  int type;
};

void dg_echo (int sockfd, struct sockaddr *pcliaddr, socklen_t clilen);

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

  int sockfd;
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;
  int SERV_PORT = atoi (argv[1]);   ///This will grab the port to listen to 
  int dropc = atoi (argv[2]);
  if (SERV_PORT <= 1023)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Error: Port given can not be less than 1023\n");
      exit (1);
    }
  if (SERV_PORT > 65535)
    {
      fprintf (stderr,
           "Error: Port given can not be more than 65535 or less than 1024\n");
      exit (1);
    }

  sockfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

  bzero (&servaddr, sizeof (servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons (INADDR_ANY);
  servaddr.sin_port = htons (SERV_PORT);

  int bb = bind (sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof (servaddr));
  if (bb < 0)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Binding failure");
    }

  dg_echo (sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, sizeof (cliaddr));

  close (sockfd);
  return 0;

}


void
dg_echo (int sockfd, struct sockaddr *pcliaddr, socklen_t clilen)
{
  int n;
  FILE *outfile = NULL;
  socklen_t len;
  char mesg[MAXLINE];
  struct packetdata newpackets;
  char filename[MAXLINE];
  recvfrom (sockfd, filename, MAXLINE, 0, pcliaddr, &len);
  printf ("Name: %s", filename);
  for (;;)
    {
      len = clilen;
      //printf("HERe");
      if ((outfile = fopen (filename, "a")) == NULL)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "\nwriting File was not opened\n");
      exit (1);
    }
      ssize_t rlen =recvfrom(sockfd, &newpackets, sizeof (newpackets), 0, pcliaddr, &len);
    if (rlen ==-1){
      printf ("failed recv");
      return 1;
    }
      printf ("\nData: %s\n", newpackets.data);
      //fprintf(outfile, "%d",newpackets.data );
      fwrite(newpackets.data,rlen,1,outfile);
      // sendto(sockfd, mesg, n, 0, pcliaddr, len);
    }
}
```

Here is the client code:

```
//client side 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include  <stdint.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAXLINE 4096
#define totaltries 3


struct packetdata data (int seqnumber, int lenght, char*data);
struct packetdata
{
  int seqnumber;
  int lenght;
  char data[MAXLINE];
  int type;
};

struct ackdata
{
    int ack;
    int type;
};


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int sockfd;
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
  FILE *infile = NULL;

  int countpackets;
  float calc;

  int tries = 0;
  int base = 0;
  int sequencenumber = 0;
  int datasize =0;

  int winsz = atoi (argv[4]); //this is for the window size
  int mtu = atoi (argv[3]); //for mtu
  int SERV_PORT = atoi (argv[2]); // the port to listen to 
  

  char sendline[MAXLINE], recvline[MAXLINE];
  struct packetdata forpackets;

  if (mtu <= 0)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "MTU Error: mtu can not be less than or equal to 0\n");
      exit (1);
    }
  //you shouldnt use any ports from 0-1023
  //1024-65535 are fines
  if (SERV_PORT <= 1023)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Port Error: Port given can not be less than 1023\n");
      exit (1);
    }
  if (SERV_PORT > 65535)
    {
      fprintf (stderr,
         "Port Error: Port given can not be more than 65535 or less than 1024\n");
      exit (1);
    }

  bzero (&servaddr, sizeof (servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_port = htons (SERV_PORT);

  if (inet_pton (AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Inet Pton error");
      return 1;

    }

  if ((sockfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "\nsocket error\n");
      return 1;
    }
  if ((infile = fopen (argv[5], "r")) == NULL)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "\nReading File was not opened\n");
      return 1;
    }


    //file name sending   
  char filename[MAXLINE];
  strcpy(filename, argv[6]);
  //printf("Filename: %c", filename);
  sendto(sockfd, filename, MAXLINE, 0, (struct sockaddr * ) & servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

  //this is for calculations 
  fseek (infile, 0, SEEK_END);
  countpackets = ftell (infile);
  fseek (infile, 0, SEEK_SET);
  //  printf("countpackets %d\n",countpackets);
  //  printf("\nMTU %d\n",mtu);
  calc = countpackets / mtu; //how many buffer is
  if (countpackets % mtu)
    {
      calc++;
    }

  printf("\nCalc %f\n",calc);



  char fordata[mtu];
  //while(1){
      while (calc>=sequencenumber && sequencenumber-base<=winsz){
    fread(forpackets.data, sizeof(recvline), 1, infile);
    //printf("%s", forpackets.data);
   // strcpy(fordata, forpackets.data);
    strncpy(fordata,(sequencenumber*mtu+forpackets.data),mtu);
    printf("%s", fordata);
    forpackets = data(sequencenumber,datasize, fordata );
    printf("\nSending Packet: %d\n", sequencenumber);
      if (sendto(sockfd, &forpackets, sizeof(forpackets), 0, (struct sockaddr * ) & servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) == -1) {
    printf("failed sending");
    return 1;
  }else{
      sequencenumber++;
  }
       }


  // } 
close(sockfd);
fclose(infile);

}

struct packetdata data (int seqnumber, int lenght, char*data){
  struct packetdata dataa;
  dataa. seqnumber = seqnumber;
  dataa. lenght = lenght;
  dataa. type = 1;
  memset(dataa.data, 0, MAXLINE);
  strcpy(dataa.data, data);  

  return dataa;
}
```

Comment: You never set outfile to a valid file handle.  You should be setting it using fopen(), and checking the result to be sure it’s non-NULL, before trying to use it in an fwrite() call.

Comment: Got it, i  did not realize that i was missing to fopen. Also, upon checking the file, i am getting alot of nul characters into the file. Any thing i can do to fix this ?

Comment: The number of bytes received from `recvfrom` is _returned_. So, do: ssize_t rlen = recvfrom(...); if (rlen < 0) perror(...);` Then, do: `fwrite (newpackets.data, rlen, 1, outfile);`

Comment: Actually, it's a bit more involved than that. Note that `recvfrom` may return a "short" length. You may have to loop on it until you get the entire/complete struct before you try to `fwrite` it.

Comment: Hey craig. I used your way, but unfortunately still null characters. The file i am sending through client only have about 88 characters. Those get printed but the rest of the buffer has null characters being printed alongside it

Comment: Note that you have `int dropc = atoi(argv[2]);` but never use it. I got a segfault when I invoked with: `./server 1025`. When I commented out the line, now the program is hanging in `recvfrom`. It looks like you've devised a custom protocol (because of the `struct` you define). This looks like the server code but no client code? Without the client, I would expect this to wait.

Comment: Hey craig, i am going to update the code above and also add the client side.  I will also add commands on how to run the program. I also have not implemented drop c

Comment: I have put client side under the server added instructions on how to run. Please take a look and see if you can find the mistake . Thank you so much

Comment: I just rebuilt everything (with `-g` for debug) info. Then, I ran the server under `gdb`. I did: `set args 8500 1` and then `run`. It segfaulted and I did `tb` to get a stack traceback. Then, I did `frame 1`. It showed the line was the `fwrite`. I then did: `p outfile` and got 0x0. That is, `outfile` is `NULL`. So, there is _no_ `fopen` to set `outfile` properly

Comment: I wonder if you're mixing up some server code with client or vice-versa? I would expect the client to write to a file because you give it an `exout.txt` argument. So, how does the server know which file to output to? After the _first_ `recvfrom` we have: `filename`, how about `outfile = fopen(filename,"w");`???

Comment: In this case, I am suppose to have the server side to save data. I dont think im mixing anything for client or server. The client sends the filepath to the server

Comment: The segfault _is_ because of the missing `fopen`. I _do_ get output with the fix. But, it has lots of binary zeroes at the end because of the length stuff I mentioned in my previous comment about `fwrite` and `rlen`, which you'll need to adjust.

Comment: sorry i forgot to update the server side code, I have implemented the rlen stuff but still getting null characters. Let me update server side code so you can take a look

Comment: please take a look above with updated server code

Comment: @CraigEstey Unlike TCP's `recv()`, `recvfrom()` will always return the contents of a single UDP packet (i.e. it won't return just part of a UDP packet).  So returning a short-length isn't an issue (although if the sender sent multiple UDP packets, concatenating their results might be required)

Comment: Don't use structs as network protocols. You are relying on about a dozen properties of the compiler, including the compiler itself, and the flags used in the actual compilation run, to be identical at both ends. Devise a protocol expressed in octets and write yourself a library to send and receive it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, just to recap the comments:

1. `outfile` was missing an `fopen` call, so the server `fwrite` would segfault
2. After the fix, the output file would get extraneous zeros because the length given to `fwrite` was the whole size rather than the returned value of `recvfrom`
3. Actually, the correct length is the `length` value inside the packet

You're on the right track. The `struct` you devised has the right things in it (e.g. sequence number, type, length, data field).

I've refactored the server and client code.

An additional issue is that the server didn't know when to *stop* writing the output file. There are several ways to do this. But, the one I chose was for the client to send an *extra* data packet with a `length` field of 0.

I've adjusted both client and server to do this.

---

Here is the refactored server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#define MAXLINE 32768
struct ackdata {
    int ack;
};

struct packetdata {
    int seqnumber;
    int length;
    char data[MAXLINE];
    int type;
};

void dg_echo(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *pcliaddr, socklen_t clilen);

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;

#if 1
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: serv_port\n");
        exit(1);
    }
#endif

    int SERV_PORT = atoi(argv[1]);      // /This will grab the port to listen to
#if 0
    int dropc = atoi(argv[2]);
#endif

    if (SERV_PORT <= 1023) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Port given can not be less than 1023\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (SERV_PORT > 65535) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Port given can not be more than 65535 or less than 1024\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);

    int bb = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    if (bb < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Binding failure");
    }

    dg_echo(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr));

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;

}

void
dg_echo(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *pcliaddr, socklen_t clilen)
{
    int n;
    FILE *outfile = NULL;
    socklen_t len;
    char mesg[MAXLINE];
    struct packetdata newpackets;
    char filename[MAXLINE];

    recvfrom(sockfd, filename, MAXLINE, 0, pcliaddr, &len);
#if 0
    printf("Name: %s", filename);
#else
    printf("Name: %s\n", filename);
    outfile = fopen(filename,"w");
#endif

    for (;;) {
        len = clilen;
        // printf("HERe");
        if (recvfrom(sockfd, &newpackets, sizeof(newpackets), 0, pcliaddr, &len) == -1) {
            printf("failed recv");
            break;
        }

        printf("DEBUG: seqnumber=%d type=%d length=%d\n",
            newpackets.seqnumber,newpackets.type,newpackets.length);

        // end of file
        if (newpackets.length == 0)
            break;

        //printf("\nData: %s\n", newpackets.data);
        fwrite(newpackets.data, newpackets.length, 1, outfile);
        // sendto(sockfd, mesg, n, 0, pcliaddr, len);
    }

    if (outfile != NULL)
        fclose(outfile);
}
```

---

And, here is the refactored client code. I cleaned it up a bit.

1. I changed the code to do the `fread` directly into the packet struct's `data` field.
2. I changed the `data` function to take a pointer arg to the packet rather than returning one. This eliminates some unnecessary copying
3. I added an extra zero length data packet to indicate EOF
4. I changed the primary data read/write loop to look at the returned length from `fread` rather than (pre)calculate the number of packets.

```
//client side
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include  <stdint.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAXLINE 4096
#define totaltries 3

struct packetdata {
    int seqnumber;
    int length;
    char data[MAXLINE];
    int type;
};

struct ackdata {
    int ack;
    int type;
};

void
data(struct packetdata *pkt,int seqnumber, int length, char *data)
{

    pkt->seqnumber = seqnumber;
    pkt->length = length;
    pkt->type = 1;
    if ((length > 0) && (data != NULL))
        memcpy(pkt->data, data, length);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    FILE *infile = NULL;

    int countpackets;
    float calc;

    int tries = 0;
    int base = 0;
    int sequencenumber = 0;
    int datasize = 0;

    int winsz = atoi(argv[4]);          // this is for the window size
    int mtu = atoi(argv[3]);            // for mtu
    int SERV_PORT = atoi(argv[2]);      // the port to listen to

    char sendline[MAXLINE],
     recvline[MAXLINE];
    struct packetdata forpackets;

    if (mtu <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "MTU Error: mtu can not be less than or equal to 0\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // you shouldnt use any ports from 0-1023
    // 1024-65535 are fines
    if (SERV_PORT <= 1023) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Port Error: Port given can not be less than 1023\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (SERV_PORT > 65535) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Port Error: Port given can not be more than 65535 or less than 1024\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);

    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Inet Pton error");
        return 1;

    }

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nsocket error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if ((infile = fopen(argv[5], "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nReading File was not opened\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // file name sending
    char filename[MAXLINE];

    strcpy(filename, argv[6]);
    // printf("Filename: %c", filename);
    sendto(sockfd, filename, MAXLINE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,
        sizeof(servaddr));

    // this is for calculations
    fseek(infile, 0, SEEK_END);
    countpackets = ftell(infile);
    fseek(infile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    // printf("countpackets %d\n",countpackets);
    // printf("\nMTU %d\n",mtu);
    calc = countpackets / mtu;          // how many buffer is
    if (countpackets % mtu) {
        calc++;
    }

    printf("\nCalc %f\n", calc);

    // while(1){
#if 0
    while (calc >= sequencenumber && sequencenumber - base <= winsz) {
#else
    while (1) {
#endif
        ssize_t rlen = fread(forpackets.data, 1, sizeof(forpackets.data),
            infile);

        data(&forpackets,sequencenumber, rlen, NULL);
        printf("\nSending Packet: %d rlen=%d\n", sequencenumber,rlen);

        if (sendto(sockfd, &forpackets, sizeof(forpackets), 0,
            (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) == -1) {
            printf("failed sending");
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            sequencenumber++;
        }

        if (rlen == 0)
            break;
    }

    // }
    close(sockfd);
    fclose(infile);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Note that the client and server are "one-shots". That is, the server exits after receiving a given file.

Also, one change I didn't make was to send/receive the filename *within* a packet (with a different `type` field).

I'd change the programs to send *only* packet structs.

Then, the server could have an outer loop, to service new/different requests (e.g. it could receive a file, then send a file, etc.)

With various `type` fields (e.g.):

1. send file to server (data is filename)
2. send file to client (data is filename)
3. file data (sent by client and/or server and length of 0 indicates EOF)
4. close connection (sent by client to server)

This may be a bit of overkill for the scope of your project ...

The server could look at the IP address from `recvfrom` and keep some state in a "connection" struct, based on a match to the client IP address. For example, the connection struct could hold the `outfile` stream (instead of a single instance).

Then, the server could handle multiple/many client streams, interspersed on the same/single socket descriptor.

---

**UPDATE:**

> Hey craig. TYSM. But is there a way, where the server is not one shot go? –
> juststruggle

It starts by adding my suggestion about sending the filename inside a packet with a type.

And, having the server loop do a `switch (pkt.type)`.

I've added the ruminants of that in the code below. The client is very similar in function to before. The server will now loop after file transfer, waiting for other packets.

Note that there is a bunch of similar code between server and client. I moved some of that to a `common.c` file. Note that this is *crude*. I'd like to have a `common.h` for definitions and function prototypes and a `common.c` for common functions. But, IRL, I am being "summoned" :-) so I don't have time to fix that.

I moved the `struct` definition to that file. In the process, I notice that the size of the `data` element is different between client and server. That's a bug because `type` is at the end and would be elided/truncated because of the differing lengths of `data`

Here's `common.c`:

```
// common.c -- common code

#define MAXLINE 1024
#define totaltries 3

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...)     printf(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...)     do { } while (0)
#endif

struct packetdata {
    int type;
    int seqnumber;
    int length;
    char data[MAXLINE];
};

struct ackdata {
    int ack;
    int type;
};

enum {
    TYPE_TOSVR,
    TYPE_TOCLI,
    TYPE_DATA
};

void
pktprep(struct packetdata *pkt,int type,int seqnumber, int length, char *data)
{

    pkt->type = type;
    pkt->seqnumber = seqnumber;
    pkt->length = length;
    if ((length > 0) && (data != NULL))
        memcpy(pkt->data, data, length);

    dbgprt("pktprep: SENDPKT seq=%d type=%d length=%d\n",
        seqnumber,type,length);
}
```

Here is `server.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#include "common.c"

void dg_echo(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *pcliaddr, socklen_t clilen);

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;

#if 1
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: serv_port\n");
        exit(1);
    }
#endif

    int SERV_PORT = atoi(argv[1]);      // /This will grab the port to listen to
#if 0
    int dropc = atoi(argv[2]);
#endif

    if (SERV_PORT <= 1023) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Port given can not be less than 1023\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (SERV_PORT > 65535) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Port given can not be more than 65535 or less than 1024\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);

    int bb = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    if (bb < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Binding failure");
    }

    dg_echo(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr));

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;

}

void
dg_echo(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *pcliaddr, socklen_t clilen)
{
    int n;
    FILE *outfile = NULL;
    socklen_t len;
    char mesg[MAXLINE];
    struct packetdata pkt;
    char filename[MAXLINE];

    for (;;) {
        len = clilen;
        // printf("HERe");
        if (recvfrom(sockfd, &pkt, sizeof(pkt), 0, pcliaddr, &len) == -1) {
            printf("failed recv");
            break;
        }

        dbgprt("DEBUG: seqnumber=%d type=%d length=%d\n",
            pkt.seqnumber,pkt.type,pkt.length);

        switch (pkt.type) {
        case TYPE_TOSVR:
            dbgprt("TOSVR: %s\n", pkt.data);
            if (outfile == NULL)
                outfile = fopen(pkt.data,"w");
            break;

        case TYPE_DATA:
            // end of file
            if (pkt.length == 0) {
                if (outfile != NULL) {
                    fclose(outfile);
                    outfile = NULL;
                }
                break;
            }

            //dbgprt("\nData: %s\n", pkt.data);
            if (outfile != NULL)
                fwrite(pkt.data, pkt.length, 1, outfile);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (outfile != NULL)
        fclose(outfile);
}
```

And, here is `client.c`:

```
//client side
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include  <stdint.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "common.c"

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    FILE *infile = NULL;

    int countpackets;
    float calc;

    int tries = 0;
    int base = 0;
    int sequencenumber = 0;
    int datasize = 0;

    int winsz = atoi(argv[4]);          // this is for the window size
    int mtu = atoi(argv[3]);            // for mtu
    int SERV_PORT = atoi(argv[2]);      // the port to listen to

    char sendline[MAXLINE],
     recvline[MAXLINE];
    struct packetdata pkt;

    if (mtu <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "MTU Error: mtu can not be less than or equal to 0\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // you shouldnt use any ports from 0-1023
    // 1024-65535 are fines
    if (SERV_PORT <= 1023) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Port Error: Port given can not be less than 1023\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (SERV_PORT > 65535) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Port Error: Port given can not be more than 65535 or less than 1024\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);

    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Inet Pton error");
        return 1;

    }

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nsocket error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if ((infile = fopen(argv[5], "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nReading File was not opened\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // file name sending
    char filename[MAXLINE];

    pktprep(&pkt,TYPE_TOSVR,sequencenumber++,strlen(argv[6]) + 1,argv[6]);
    // printf("Filename: %c", filename);
#if 0
    sendto(sockfd, filename, MAXLINE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,
        sizeof(servaddr));
#else
    sendto(sockfd, &pkt, sizeof(pkt), 0,
        (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
#endif

    // this is for calculations
    fseek(infile, 0, SEEK_END);
    countpackets = ftell(infile);
    fseek(infile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    // printf("countpackets %d\n",countpackets);
    // printf("\nMTU %d\n",mtu);
    calc = countpackets / mtu;          // how many buffer is
    if (countpackets % mtu) {
        calc++;
    }

    dbgprt("\nCalc %f\n", calc);

    // while(1){
#if 0
    while (calc >= sequencenumber && sequencenumber - base <= winsz) {
#else
    while (1) {
#endif
        ssize_t rlen = fread(pkt.data, 1, sizeof(pkt.data),
            infile);

        pktprep(&pkt,TYPE_DATA,sequencenumber, rlen, NULL);

        if (sendto(sockfd, &pkt, sizeof(pkt), 0,
            (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) == -1) {
            printf("failed sending");
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            sequencenumber++;
        }

        if (rlen == 0)
            break;
    }

    // }
    close(sockfd);
    fclose(infile);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile `server.c` and `client.c` with `-DDEBUG` to start.

Comment: Hey craig. TYSM. But is there a way, where the server is not one shot go?

Comment: Can you please reedit that, i am new and accidently edited your answer to this :(

Comment: Not to worry! Edits for answers or questions that are not owned by you go into an "suggested edit queue" until you gain sufficient reputation points. They must be approved. I rejected the edit before I saw that it was you. Thanks for letting me know. Otherwise, I can "rollback" even an approved edit.

Comment: Gotchya, Is there a way to not have the server as one shot go?